# Using GRXML grammars in Sphinx4

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech, cmusphinx, sphinx4

Does sphinx support the use of GR-XML grammars, or do I have to convert my existing grammar to the java speech grammar format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does sphinx support the use of GR-XML grammars

Yes, see Dialog demo in latest version sphinx4-5prealpha

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

> or do I have to convert my existing grammar to the java speech grammar format?

No